# Would for typical behaviour or one time thing?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, modal-verbs

Consider:

1. Let's see if he would give us money.

In the example 1, the speaker is saying whether he would give money to the speaker if he asked now. Not his typical behaviour. He might give the speaker money depending on the situation.

Now consider:

2. I will fake drown to see if my dog would save me.
3. He is going to disguise as a famous actor to see how his sister would react.

Examples 2 or 3 are confusing me.

In the Example 2, I don't know whether I should interpret as the owner testing if his dog would save him if he drowned or if his dog would save if he drowned  at that specific time.

Same for the Example 3.

If the dog saved his owner, that wouldn't necessarily mean that the dog would save if its owner drowned. Right? The speaker is just imagining that specific hypothetical situation. Right?

So I would appreciate any answer that would relieve my confusion.

Comment: 2. and 3. are not grammatically correct. I can't understand it either.

Comment: The original is actually "Man pretended to fake drown to see if his dog would save him.

Comment: that sounds about right

Comment: Why is WOULD used then?

Comment: Would is expressing the conditional mood indicating the consequence of an imagined event or situation.

Comment: Then why is 2 wrong?

Comment: *Will* can also technically be used

Comment: so where you wrote it above is different than how it was originally written and it is not written grammatically right. If you add *if* between *see* and *my*, then it is correct.

Comment: Oh its mistake i ll correct it.

Comment: Ok i corrected so that you can answer my question if you would.

Comment: Does the would i just used correct and if correct, why?

Comment: If the dog saved his owner, that wouldn't necessarily mean that the dog would save if its owner drowned. Right? The speaker is just imagining that specific hyphothetical situation. Right?

Comment: *to see if* are the key words

Comment: Grammar aside, do you have an actual language question here? Or is the problem that you find hypothetical situations confusing?

Comment: I mean both......